# how to select an item in listbox in windows phone 7.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

i'm a beginner and creating an app for windows phone 7.1 and i'm trying to navigate to a new page through the click event in the the list box, basically i want that every item in the list box should navigate to different page i have tried the following code

```
private void FirstListBox_SelectionChanged_1(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
     {
        // If selected index is -1 (no selection) do nothing
        if (FirstListBox.SelectedIndex == -1)
            return;

        // Navigate to the new page
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/FirstItemPage1.xaml?selectedItem=" + FirstListBox.SelectedIndex, UriKind.Relative));

        // Reset selected index to -1 (no selection)
        FirstListBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
```

the above code works well but the problem is it takes the whole list box to the same page but i want that every individual item to navigate to a different page

Comment: Yes ofcourse it will move to the same page, but how do you want to move to different page, i mean based on any condition?

Comment: i want that every item in the list box should navigate to different page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the SelectedValue for each item in the listBox when adding them to the ListBox.

Let's say you assign a list of strings to the ItemsSource of the ListBox through code (or it may happend through data binding). You may add your items in the constructor of your page.

```
var items = new List<string>(){ "Home", "Details" };
FirstListBox.ItemsSource = items;
```

In the SelectionChanged event add a switch statement that navigates to different pages based on the SelectedValue of the selected item like so:

```
private void FirstListBox_SelectionChanged_1(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
 {
    // If selected index is -1 (no selection) do nothing
    if (FirstListBox.SelectedIndex == -1)
        return;

    switch (FirstListBox.SelectedValue)
        {
            case "Home":// Navigate to the page
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Home.xaml", UriKind.Relative)); break;
            case "Details":// Navigate to the page
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Details.xaml", UriKind.Relative)); break;default:break;
        }


    // Reset selected index to -1 (no selection)
    FirstListBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
}
```

In case you Bind complex objects to the ListBox, you can use the SelectedItem-Property of the ListBox as that property contains the object that has been bound to that ListBoxItem and distinguish between the cases based on one of the properties of the complex object, like a name or id.

Comment: executed the above code by adding a default case

                 default:
                     MessageBox.Show("Select a function!");
                     break;

and the output just gives the default case and doesnot navigate to new page help would be appreciated

Comment: How do you create the ListBoxItems for the ListBox? Through binding a data source to the ListBox?

Comment: I've added an explanation for the case of binding complex objects to the ListBox.

Comment: thank you steve i got the app working with your code and some modifications i have left the working code here

Comment: @MustansirSabir You could mark my answer as the 'correct answer' :-)

Answer (score 0):

i got my app working with this code

private void SecondListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            {
                if (SecondListBox.SelectedIndex == -1)
                    return;

```
           ItemViewModel itemViewModel = SecondListBox.SelectedItem as ItemViewModel ;

            switch (itemViewModel.LineOne)
            {
                case "Violet":
                    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/SecondListPage1.xaml?selectedItem=" + SecondListBox.SelectedIndex, UriKind.Relative));
                    break;
                case "Indigo":
                    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/SecondListPage2.xaml?selectedItem=" + SecondListBox.SelectedIndex, UriKind.Relative));
                    break;
                case "Blue":
                    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/SecondListPage3.xaml?selectedItem=" + SecondListBox.SelectedIndex, UriKind.Relative));
                    break;
                case "Green":
                    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/SecondListPage4.xaml?selectedItem=" + SecondListBox.SelectedIndex, UriKind.Relative));
                    break;
                case "Yellow":
                    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/SecondListPage5.xaml?selectedItem=" + SecondListBox.SelectedIndex, UriKind.Relative));
                    break;
                case "Orange":
                    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/SecondListPage6.xaml?selectedItem=" + SecondListBox.SelectedIndex, UriKind.Relative));
                    break;
                case "Red":
                    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/SecondListPage7.xaml?selectedItem=" + SecondListBox.SelectedIndex, UriKind.Relative));
                    break;
                case "Purple":
                    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/SecondListPage8.xaml?selectedItem=" + SecondListBox.SelectedIndex, UriKind.Relative));
                    break;
                default:
                    MessageBox.Show("Please Select From the list!");
                    break;




            }


            SecondListBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
        }
    }
```